# How to integrate a typeform like experience for CRUD website

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I'm building a web app and I want to have a [typeform](https://www.typeform.com/) like flow to create and edit entities on my website.
As far as I know, I can't use typeform itself, as they don't allow for edits.

Is there a tool/snippet/package to create good looking forms, without refresh between pages, include animations, skip logic etc.?

I'm using django for my website.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

Trying to use Barba.js and I have an issue with the enter transition.
The exit transition to works fine, but for some reason the entry transition doesn't work.

The new  just appears without fading in.

HTML Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BarbaJS legacy example</title>
</head>

<body>
  {% load static %}
  <!-- define the wrapper and the container -->
  <div data-barba="wrapper">
    <h1>
      base base base
    </h1>

    <div data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="test-1" id="test">
      <h3>
        this text should be replaced
      </h3>

      <a href="/test2">test</a>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- load barba (UMD version) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core"></script>


  <script src="{% static "app/js/test.js" %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML TEST 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BarbaJS legacy example</title>
</head>

<body>
    {% load static %}
    <!-- define the wrapper and the container -->
    <div data-barba="wrapper">
        <h1>
            base base base
        </h1>

        <div data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="test-1" id="test">
            <h3>
                New text
                New text
                New text
            </h3>

            <a href="/test">test</a>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- load barba (UMD version) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@barba/core"></script>


    <script src="{% static "app/js/test.js" %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  barba.init({

    transitions: [{
      leave(data) {

        return $(data.current.container).fadeOut().promise()
      },
      enter(data) {

        return $(data.next.container).fadeIn().promise()

      }
    }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because in HTML 2; you have the container set to an opacity of 1 by default. So when loading the next container and calling `fadeIn()` it's trying to fade from an opacity of 1 to 1.

If you hide the container initially you will then be able to fade the container in.

On the Barba site, the legacy example use GSAP animation which is doing the above already i.e. setting opacity to 0 then to 1.

Please see below for exmaple setup - HTML 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BarbaJS legacy example</title>
</head>

<body>

<style>
    .hidden {
        opacity: 0
    }
</style>

<!-- define the wrapper and the container -->
<div data-barba="wrapper">
    <div data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="page-a">
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <a href="/test2.html">Page</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- load barba (UMD version) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>

<!-- load gsap animation library (minified version) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gsap@latest/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

HTML PAGE 2:

```
<div data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="page-b" class="hidden">
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <h1>Hello</h1>
 <a href="/">test</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    barba.init({
        transitions: [{
            leave(data) {
                return $(data.current.container).fadeOut().promise()
            },
            enter(data) {
                return $(data.next.container).fadeTo(400, 1).promise()
            }
        }]
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't resolve my issue. The opacity of HTML 2 remains 0 when the second page loads. I even copy and pasted your reply without success

Comment: Please take a look at this example; using the code I provided. The implementation you've setup may be incorrect. Please follow the link and click preview to run the code and you will see this working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bJUOlO3jyQRka0fp?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 1):

You could try Barba.js for smooth page transitions with no refreshing between pages:

https://barba.js.org/

Or opt for a animation solution only using GreenSock to build and animate the form to achieve a typeform style form:

https://greensock.com/

Comment: Thank you! What's the advantage in using barba.js vs. fetching the next page with Ajax and replacing the html component's content?

Comment: No problem! Depending on the use case; the barba lifecycle is more comprehensive and will allow for easier transitions from one 'view'/page to the next with beforeLeave, beforeEnter hooks. Barba uses PJAX, so you can control the URL without refreshing; meaning you have access to the browser history and back buttons if required. It's also faster with prefetching. However, depending on the form complexity it can take longer to implement over simple ajax calls.

Comment: I am having some issues with the Barba js implementation. The entry transition works, but the entry doesn't. The new div just appears, without the fadeIn animation.  Any idea why?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup for the test 2 page?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Thank you. Just added the solution to a new answer, I hope this resolves this issue for you and clarifies why this was happening.